# v6 Supercharger with Multitask Manager and Tag Home Launchers

Tags: ram, launcher, multitasking

I would like to make both launchers Hard To Kill.

- Tag Home takes way too long to load from cold start because it has to load ~200 app tags from a database into memory. However, it only occupies 8MB itself. However, it usually dies after a while.
- Multitask Manager is also lightweight, and I need it to switch from app to app. I use this as my 'default' launcher. I open up Tag Home from Multitask Manager.

The problem is, [v6 supercharger](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=991276) seems to only recognize Multitask Manager as my Homescreen Launcher. The actual launcher -- Tag Home -- is ignored.

Is there any script/method to make Tag Home 'Hard To Kill' while maintaining Multitask Manager as my default launcher?

Comment: That sounds like a funny counter-ad. The XDA page you linked says about the product: "It rearranges and fixes the OOM Groupings and Priorites and lowmemorykiller values." Looks like it forget about its own -- or the OOM would not kick it out. The only way I know of has to be done by the developer: He could have the app causing to (optionally) run a background service, thus moving it to the category of "less likely to be killed" apps. I'd suggest visiting the quoted link and ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you mention also offers an option to make additional apps 'bulletproof'.

Since I don't know which version of Supercharger you're running, I can't tell you the correct number of the mentioned option, but it's labeled `BulletProof Apps {Hit or Miss}`.

It scans the current process list and gives you the option to name the app you want to make immune (or rather "resistent") to being killed by the low memory killer. You don't have to be very precise with the naming, any 3 following letters matching your process should suffice. It will then prompt you to acknowledge the choice.

That's it, you're done!